# Node JS prompt library doesn't hide password

Tags: node.js, properties, hidden, prompt

I'm using the prompt library for Node.js and I have this code:

```
// Entry point for the program
var prompt =require ('prompt' )
var Basic = require('./helper/basic')
var program = require('./helper/cli-args')

var pwd = new Basic()

var promptSchema = {
  properties: {
    sprintID: {
      description: "Enter sprint ID",
      type: 'integer'
    },
    password: {
      description: "Enter the password for " + program.user,
      hidden: true
    }
  }
}
prompt.start()
prompt.get(promptSchema, function (err,result) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  program.sprint = result.sprintID
  pwd.setDigest(result.password)
  prompt.stop()
  console.log ("Sprint ID: ", program.sprint)
  console.log("Basic: ", pwd.digest);
})
```

The Basic class is very simple :

```
// Basic authentication
var base64 = require('base-64')
var program = require ('../helper/cli-args')

class Basic {
  setDigest(pwd) {
    this.digest = base64.encode(program.user.concat(":").concat(pwd))
  }
}
module.exports = Basic
```

The problem I have is that the promp doesn't hide the password.
Here is an output:

> $ npm start
>
> jira@1.0.0 start D:\Documents\Programmation\NodeJS\jira
> node index.js
>
> prompt: Enter sprint ID: 156
> prompt: Enter the password for sikkache: **Not the real Password**
> Sprint ID:  156
> Basic:  c2lra2FjaGU6Tm90IHRoZSByZWFsIFBhc3N3b3Jk

As you can see, the password is clear.

Can anyone help me, I really need the password to be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync) module

it has an option called hideEchoBack which hides typed text on screen with *

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

// Wait for user's response. 
var userName = readlineSync.question('May I have your name? ');
console.log('Hi ' + userName + '!');

// Handle the secret text (e.g. password). 
var favFood = readlineSync.question('What is your favorite food? ', {
  hideEchoBack: true // The typed text on screen is hidden by `*` (default). 
});
console.log('Oh, ' + userName + ' loves ' + favFood + '!');
```

Comment: Doesn't work on gitbash (I'm working on windows, shame on me), but it works on powershell 8o